# What kind of a bathroom vent is this? How do I open it?

Tags: bathroom, vent

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb6gt.jpg

See picture.
Bathroom vent doesn't appear to be sucking, so I want to open it and see if it's something to do with the fan.  If the fan looks fine I think I'll have to hire a professional to check the piping to make sure it isn't clogged.

Answer (score 1):

We have a fan like that.  The external body pulls straight down a couple inches and hangs on a pair of wire, spring-like supports.  From there, you can access the light bulb and a bit of the fan.

I haven't done it, but from there, I would assume you can remove the fan and get a look at the vent pipe.  For us, the alternative would be to attempt to access from above via the attic.  That may be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

SredniV has it right. Just pull downward on the bezel. You'll feel that there are two points on opposite sides that are hang from springs. The legs of the spring are squeezed together, and together they are inserted into a short slot, where they spread open as the bezel is lifted up toward the fixture.

Once you pull the bezel down far enough so that you can reach the springs, pinch the legs together and the whole spring assembly will be released from the fixture on that side.

It looks like a Nutone, if you want to find it on their support pages. One site I looked at showed model 8663RP looked like that, but on Nutone page it looked superficially different.